# SMTP 535 5.7.0 Error: authentication failed

Tags: codeigniter, swiftmailer, smtp-auth

I used SMTP protocol for sending email in my system.The system is developed with Codeigniter.in the system two types of email sending functionality, one is from codeigniter Email libraries and  other is from swift mailer.In codeigniter it is working but in swift mailer an authentication failure message is shown.

Both functions use same login details.The port used is 25.

Comment: Are you using `gmail smtp` or not? If yes than `smtp_port is 465`.If you are sending mail from `localhost` than you have to use `gmail smtp` settings.

Comment: iam using my own mail server.

Comment: can you please post the error and if you are not getting any error than check your `spam` in your mailbox.sometimes this kind of mail directly goes to `spam` instead of our `inbox`

Comment: I runed swiftmailer through command promt, then authentication failure message is shown.

Comment: And also using telnet the same error message is shown

Comment: this is error message getting from telnet
535 5.7.0 authentication failed

Comment: And this is error message getting from swift mailer
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Swift_TransportException' with message 'Failed
to authenticate on SMTP server with username "info@yugakusha.net" using 1 possib
le authenticators' in C:\scheduler\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\Esmtp\AuthHandler
.php:176

Answer (score 0):

Give a try with this **gmail smtp**

```
$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.gmail.com', 465, 'ssl')
     ->setUsername('YOUR_GMAIL_ID')
     ->setPassword('YOUR_GMAIL_PASSWORD') ;
```

If it works with this than I think your hosting provider not giving smtp service to you so, you need to contact your hosting provider.